# Integration between two systems using TIBCO

Tags: windows-services, tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-business-works, system-integration

I have two different applications that need to share data between them. By data, I mean only some pieces of data and not the entire data across the systems.

The databases of the applications are owned by us but the applications are third party.

The two applications use database as an integration mechanism where they have a transaction table into which the data to be integrated is written to. A third party application then picks the data from there.

We are evaluating how to utilize TIBCO for performing the integration - (Trying to go away from the third party integration pieces). Such that, we expect Tibco to pick the data from the transaction table, apply any business logic and sync up the other systems as result of the integration.

I have in the past wrote a windows service that polls a similar transaction table and write (the data to be synced/integrated) to the TIBCO queue and have the windows service read from the queue, apply the business logic and do the integration or data sync in the other system's database.

I was using TIBCO EMS module to work with the message queues. But if there are other options within and outside of TIBCO, please provide some pointers.

We are particular on TIBCO because the org moves in a direction to make TIBCO a standard means of integration between systems.

TIA

Comment: Tibco business works - aka Active matrix Business Works is the product that i would need and ADB - active database adapters and BW business processes (aka process definitions) is the solution i would need. Just wanted to clarify both the answers below are tangential to my question. Btw TIbco BW lets you create business processes using "Palettes" ADB is one such a palette.

Comment: you could also do this with Spring or our MarketDataIntegrator, check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0Q6pawEjpA - it's talking about Bloomberg but it doesn't have to be

Answer (score 1):

[TIBCO BusinessWorks](http://www.tibco.com/products/tibco-businessworks) Product is the right option for you here in this where it allows you to connect to the database / ems, I believe. This allows to integrate systems and define your process and orchestrate the logic you might wanted to do.

It has the connection palette to connect to database, fetches the required data using query and allows to process that data for further processing.

May be you can find more details in [documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.3.4/doc/html/GUID-8CE1DA74-12EE-47C8-8D71-66702F4E0099.html)

Comment: Appreciate if this is accepted as answer if you find it helpful.